# How to get view from drawer header layout with binding in activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, view, binding, drawer

So this is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="MainActivity"
    >
    <!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
             space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar"
                        tools:text="@string/default_toolbar_title"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_fuf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/flamme"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            **app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"**
            app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item_color_selector"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

and I am using binding for the activity so I don't have to use the findViewById and cast it etc.. like this:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = binding.myAwesomeToolbar;
        toolbarTitle = binding.toolbarTitle;
        BalrogFontsHelper.SetKhandBoldToView(toolbarTitle);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_dehaze_white_24);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }


        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout;
        **tvLoggedUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_logged_user_email);**
        BalrogFontsHelper.SetKhandBoldToView(tvLoggedUserEmail);
```

As you can see, I can get the views that are directly in the activity_main.xml layout by binding but when the view I am trying to get is not there I can't see the variable in the binding object.

drawer_header.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_logged_user_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        tools:text="@string/login_placeholder_email"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

How could I get this tv_logged_user_email TextView in a binding way so I have:

```
**tvLoggedUserEmail = binding.tvLoggedUserEmail;**
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Updated solution (13/11/2015)

Solution: Update your Design Support Library to `23.1.1`:

> Changes for Design Support library `23.1.1`:
>
> - Added the `getHeaderView` method to the `NavigationView` class.
> - Fixed a transparent background issue for a `FloatingActionButton` object on devices running Android 4.0 (API level 15) and lower. (Issue 183315)

See https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html for more info

---

## Original solution

I don't know why there is no method which provides header view
attached programmatically.

Instead, here's two solutions:

```java
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.header_layout)
ImageView iv = (ImageView)headerview.findViewById(R.id.your_image_view)
```

Or:

```java
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, navigationView, false);
navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);

ImageView iv = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.yourImageView)
```

Comment: Just update your gradle file to get 23.1.1 and the getHeaderView(int index) method will be there.

Comment: Life saver!! +1.. But you have to remove app:headerLayout="@layout/header_left" from xml otherwise it will inflate two headers ...

Answer (score 56):

If you set `app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header` then you don't have to inflate the view again. You can just use `.bind` instead of `.inflate`.

You can get the already inflated header view and bind it like this:

```
View headerView = binding.navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
DrawerHeaderBinding headerBinding = DrawerHeaderBinding.bind(headerView);
```

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: best solution by far

Comment: I found it very useful. Worked like charm.

Comment: The best solution, always go for the simplest solution that makes sense.

Answer (score 20):

I have a slightly cleaner solution, where I don't have to "pollute" fragment/activity with code responsible for inflating and adding header view to NavigationView. I implemented extension class for NavigationView. I did that like this:

Layout of my activity:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="dashboard"
        type="ramps.view.model.DashboardScreenViewModel"/>
</data>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        bind:dashboard="@{dashboard}"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:navigationItemSelectedListener="@{dashboard.onMenuItemSelected}"
        app:model="@{dashboard.score}"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As you can see, there is no app:headerLayout in NavigationView, but I have added my custom app:model, with data I want to pass to the header layout.
How did I define this custom parameter? By extension class:

```
public class NavigationViewExtensions {

@BindingAdapter({"bind:model"})
public static void loadHeader(NavigationView view, ScoreViewModel model) {
    ViewNavigationHeaderBinding binding = ViewNavigationHeaderBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()));
    binding.setScore(model);
    binding.executePendingBindings();
    view.addHeaderView(binding.getRoot());
  }
}
```

Just place this class anywhere in your project. And the layout of my header:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<data>

    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <variable
        name="score"
        type="ramps.view.model.ScoreViewModel"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/graphite"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_large"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_large"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/player_details_header_score"
        layout="@layout/view_avatar_score_header"
        bind:score="@{score}"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This reply should be accepted answer. Excellent post.

Comment: this is confusing, Can you please show the ScoreViewModel class?

Answer (score 13):

I have/had the same problem.

A workaround is to inflate the header view and add it programatically.

Like this:

```
DrawerHeaderBinding drawerHeaderBinding = DrawerHeaderBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(navigationView.getContext()));
navigationView.addHeaderView(drawerHeaderBinding.getRoot());
drawerHeaderBinding.tvLoggedUserEmail = "email";
drawerHeaderBinding.executePendingBindings();
```

So remove the app:headerLayout and do it programatically. I do think google should fix the core issue here though, either in the design library or in the data binding library.

Comment: To keep height of RelativeLayout specified in layout_height, put RelativeLayout into frame layout: `<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
`

Comment: did you notice changes in design-23.1.0? My code wouldn't work now.

Answer (score 10):

Quite a simple solution here. Let's suppose you added your NavigationView as

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/my_nav_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer"/>
```

And that you want to access a TextView in `my_nav_drawer_header.xml` that has an id of `textView2`. So you would just use this code in your activity:

```
View headerContainer = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); // This returns the container layout from your navigation drawer header layout file (e.g., the parent RelativeLayout/LinearLayout in your my_nav_drawer_header.xml file)
TextView textView2 = (TextView)headerContainer.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
textView2.setText("Sorted!");
```

No need to inflate or interfere with your existing code, etc.

Answer (score 9):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (flag) {
            navigationView.getMenu().clear(); //clear old inflated items.
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.drawer_view1);
            flag = false;
        } else {
            navigationView.getMenu().clear(); //clear old inflated items.
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.drawer_view);
            flag = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with DataBinding library it works for me.

**navigation_view_header.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_view_header_height"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/navigation_view_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/navigation_view_top_padding"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_dimen"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/avatar"
        android:text="email"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="navigationItemSelectedListener"
            type="com.example.MainActivity"/>
    </data>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:tag="layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar.Theme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_view_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:navigationItemSelectedListener="@{navigationItemSelectedListener::onNavigationItemSelected}"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

and within your activity:

```
ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
                R.layout.activity_main);
activityMainBinding.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);/* with this line navigation menu item selection events are handled in onNavigationItemSelected() specified in navigation_view_header.xml*/

NavigationViewHeaderBinding navigationViewHeaderBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.navigation_view_header,activityMainBinding.navigationView,false);
        activityMainBinding.navigationView.addHeaderView(navigationViewHeaderBinding.getRoot());
```

and make sure your activity implements `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Answer (score 0):

- Edit your gradle file to update **com.android.support** libraries to version **23.1.1** or beyond.
- Use `navigationView.getHeaderView(i)`, where `i` is the index of the `headerview`. If you just defined this view on layout, is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated build tools from Android sdk manager, then `23.1.0` is also working fine for me.

I am using `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` Before this it was `23.0.1`.

and there is no need of using:

```
(View) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.idOfViewFromHeaderView);
```

In your activity you can directly use:

```
(View) findViewById(R.id.idOfViewFromHeaderView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put navigationView.getHeaderView(0) then use any views

```
        TextView profile,info;
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        profile = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile);
        info = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.info);
        profile.setOnClickListener(this);
        info.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

It works for me.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    NavHeaderMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.nav_header_main, navigationView, false);

    navigationView.addHeaderView(binding.getRoot());
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_header.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="account"
        type="lonja.dreamteam.su.trainingdiary.view_model.AccountViewModel"/>

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/header_background"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:src="@{account.sex}"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:civ_border_width="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@{account.name}"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to describe what you have done not just post code ... in effort to maximize benefit to others

Answer (score -2):

You can do this. First initialize the navigation view.

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
```

and then initialize all the views that is inside of navigationView.

```
    CircleImageView circleView = (CircleImageView) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);
    TextView name = (TextView) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView email = (TextView) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.header);
```

and then you can use those views as you wish.
eg:

```
        name.setText(NAME);
        email.setText(EMAIL);
```

Comment: That's not using binding. I know how to do that. But thanks.