# Navigation drawer in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I know it should be in the style sheet area for this, but when I created a new Android app using Android Studio, it has a user logo and user information in a green box. This is what I want to edit.

First it should ask them to login if first time using the app.

[image: Navigation Drawer Activity]

But let's deal with one thing at a time, and first is me getting use to where Google puts things.

Comment: I wonder, would you delete this question? It has not attracted any (useful) answers in ~18 months, and isn't very clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your layout activiy you will find a "NavigationView", there are 2 attributes there you need "header" and "menu".

You can see in this answer how.to get the views inside the "header" file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33631797/4017501

There is another alternative. The "NavigationView" is a ViewGroup. So you can use it as such. Delete thee "header" and "menu" attribute and add the closing brackets as if were a ViewGroup:

```
<NavigationView></NavigationView>
```

Now you can simply put a fragment inside and then find every view and handle your logic from the fragment, is a more direct and customizable approach.