# How to refresh the headview content of navigationview in android

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

Hello I am using `NavigationView` in one the demo project. I have header layout of `NavigationView`. I am getting data of header layout at the runtime and once I get data I am setting values of views but data is not reflected or refreshed.

```
((TextView)headerNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.username)).setText(userData.getName());
```

What is the correct way to refresh the navigationview at runtime once we get a data from web service.

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246360/how-to-get-view-from-drawer-header-layout-with-binding-in-activity) helps you.

Comment: Did you call invalidate for NavigationView?

Comment: Yes I tried but it is not working

Comment: @pRaNaY that thread is for different purpose

Comment: @Williams can you put some part your code ?

Comment: @Amir there is callback of volley in which I am getting response of web service & then I am trying to set the value of textview which I got from web service

Comment: @Williams I do it many times and have not problem. Did response of your **volley** Okay ?

Comment: Are you sure you are on the UI thread?

Comment: The way you set text is correct, so I bet you're doing it from the background thread. Try to wrap your code-snippet into `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){  <UI update>
    }
});`

Comment: @JaredRummler Yes I am running on UI thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue: it's not as much an issue with your webservice etc. than a bug in Android with the NavigationView Header. 
The workaround is to inflate the header programmatically like below... Let's assume you have a TextView called "version" in the header :

```
NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);    
View headerLayout = mNavigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.my_header_layout);
// Now you can update the views in your header as you want :
TextView version = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.version);
version.setText("text in my header");
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to try code like below to get `View` from Navigationview.

For Android support 23.1.0 can be to use a `addOnLayoutChangeListener`. Somenthing like:

```
headerNavigationView.addOnLayoutChangeListener( new View.OnLayoutChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange( ... )
    {
        navigationView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener( this );

        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
        TextView tvUsername = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.R.id.username);
        tvUsername.setText(userData.getName());
    }
} );
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161345/android-support-v23-1-0-update-breaks-navigationview-get-find-header) answer.

I hope it's helps you.

Comment: I am already doing that.. my `headerNavigationView` is the header view.. my question is not how to get view from navigation view..I am getting that but value is not being refreshed

Comment: it is not related to my question.. started bounty

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of NavigationView changed recently.  You can no longer reach into NavigationView to find the header of a particular id.  Instead you should use [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) to add a view of your own createion or [inflateHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#inflateHeaderView(int)), which returns the view you're looking for.