# Android drawer layout header - cannot access it

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

In my past project from the beggining of the year I have set the content of my drawerHeader in the mainActivity code. I am rewriting it and now it seems impossible to access the header through binding in MainActivity.

I have a usual drawer layout in the activity -> navigation view -> drawer header.
I used to access it through simple binding.layoutDrawer.userDataHeader but it doesn't find userDataHeader no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

main activity layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="mainActivity"
            type="com.kerubyte.engagecommerce.presentation.ui.activity.MainActivity" />

    </data>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".presentation.ui.activity.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_activity_main_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".presentation.ui.activity.MainActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_actionbar_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_open_drawer_action"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:onClick="@{() -> mainActivity.openDrawerMenu()}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_hamburger" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_open_profile_action"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:onClick="@{() -> mainActivity.onProfileClick()}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_open_cart_action"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image_open_cart_action"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_open_cart_action"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_open_cart_action"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_user_cart_items_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_open_cart_action"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/image_open_cart_action"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.55"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image_open_cart_action"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_open_cart_action" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_actionbar_root"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/layout_navigation_menu"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:maxWidth="300dp"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

drawer header layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/user_data_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_user_avatar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:riv_oval="true"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_avatar_support"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_user_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/image_user_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image_user_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_user_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_user_email"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_user_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_user_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_user_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_user_avatar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Main Activity

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mainViewModel: ActivityMainViewModel by viewModels()
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil
            .setContentView(
                this,
                R.layout.activity_main
            )

        navigationView = binding.layoutNavigationMenu
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(
            this,
            R.id.nav_host_fragment
        )
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController)

        setBindings()
        setupObserver()
    }

private fun updateDrawerHeader(user: User) {
        binding.layoutDrawer.userDataHeader.text_first_name_value_header.text = user.firstName
        binding.layoutDrawer.userDataHeader.text_last_name_value_header.text = user.lastName
        binding.layoutDrawer.userDataHeader.text_email_value_header.text = user.email

}
}
```

And Im trying to update the header with

```
private fun updateDrawerHeader(user: User) {
        binding.layoutDrawer.userDataHeader.text_first_name_value_header.text = user.firstName
        binding.layoutDrawer.userDataHeader.text_last_name_value_header.text = user.lastName
        binding.layoutDrawer.userDataHeader.text_email_value_header.text = user.email
    
}
```

userDataHeader I cannot find.

Comment: Which the type of binding.layoutDrawer ? Is it the ViewBindingImpl or something else?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I have updated my OP to show my MainActivity

Comment: debug, and see the value of ```binding.layoutDrawer``` it may not be the type you expect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get view from drawer header layout with binding in activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246360/how-to-get-view-from-drawer-header-layout-with-binding-in-activity)